# Does renice on a parent renice the child?

Tags: shell, nice, renice

I know if I nice a shell script (ie: before it runs) all processes that start from the shell script will also be niced.

What if I start a shell script and the renice it, do all the child processes become reniced as well?

Looked in the renice man pages and there are no mention of child processes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Children inherit the *current* priority of a process when they're created. That means, if you renice the parent and start a child, it will have the modified priority.

Children that are already running when you renice are not affected.

The clue is in the `fork()` man pages (starting a child is a `fork/exec` operation):

> fork() creates a child process that differs from the parent process only in its PID and PPID, and in the fact that resource utilizations are set to 0.

Comment: In the case of a shell using the process group (-g) option of renice also won't change currently running children as each command they execute goes into a different process group.  But most programs will not change the process group of their children so it's a way to alter related processes.

Comment: Yeah, I figured by "renice on a parent", the questioner meant that specific PID. Obviously if you renice a process group or user, other processes may be affected.

Comment: @paxdiablo:I want child process to start with its default priority 0 not on priority of parent process then?

Comment: @Rahul, the correct way to ask a question is _ask a question,_ not make a comment to a question that almost no-one bar the author will see.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Already asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904588/niced-process-gives-their-priority-to-child-process?