# Run high-priority sshd process without inheriting that priority to child process

Tags: linux, openssh, nice

I have given highest priority to sshd process using following command:

```
nice -n -20 /sbin/sshd
```

But it will give highest priority to child process (/bin/sh) also by default. So, is it possible to give normal priority (0) to child process instead of highest priority?

Comment: This might be a solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795666/automatically-adjusting-process-priorities-under-linux

Comment: @RicardoJ:Sorry I'm taking about child process's priority

Comment: _My_ question would be: why do you think it necessary to run `sshd` at elevated priority?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm running openssh in embedded system with low cpu

Comment: Nice-levels are inherited to child processes and that's the way it will be, unless you do some heavy patching on fock() and friends. See, e.g., http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37896/nice-and-child-processes .

Comment: @SamiLaine: Possible if we set default priority to parent process before forking child ..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to give normal priority to child process of niced process but we can assign normal priority in parent process code after `fork()` and before `exec()` of the child, this way we can assign normal priority to child process.

Refer [setpriority](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpriority.html) for setting priority for any process from code

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this sshd is OpenSSH v4.4 or newer, you can probably get the effect you are looking for by setting the ForceCommand option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to something like:

```
ForceCommand nice -n 0 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

The ForceCommand feature is documented [here](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config). You can also use a Match block (documented in the same place) to modify the behavior for certain ports, users, IP addresses, etc.

The main gotcha (not mentioned in the docs) is that ForceCommand runs on the user's shell AFTER the execution of initialization scripts (eg .bashrc, etc) so the lowered priority won't apply until those startup scripts complete (hopefully those aren't doing anything compute intensive...).

Answer (score -1):

Try using a niced [shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/106722/choosing-the-shell-that-ssh-uses) command interpreter.

```
chsh -s "/usr/bin/nice -n 0 /bin/bash" username
```

Replace bash  with your favorite shell.

You might get unexpected results by doing so, so please keep an extra session open as recovery option.